# How do I generate random text in NLTK 3.0?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

The generate method of nltk.text.Text seems to have been removed in NLTK 3.0.

For example:

```
>>> bible = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words(u'bible-kjv.txt')
>>> bibleText = nltk.Text(bible)
>>> bibleText.generate()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'generate'
```

It may just be that I'm remembering wrongly how to do this, but everything I can find online seems to support the above method. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use the lorem ipsum Python package. No need for NLTK.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A note in the [first online chapter of the NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html#searching-text) says that:

> The generate() method is not available in NLTK 3.0 but will be
>   reinstated in a subsequent version.

Comment: Is there an alternative to `generate()`?