# What should we use instead of nltk.Text.generate()?

Tags: nltk

It seems that `nltk.Text.generate()` is not available in NLTK 3.0 ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183145/how-do-i-generate-random-text-in-nltk-3-0)). How should we be generating sentences instead? Thanks.

Comment: write your own ngram generator hahaa... it's not that hard.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the `generate()` function relied on a buggy implementation of ngram models. It has been removed from NLTK 3.0 until someone can get around to fixing it, as you can see [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/367) (search for the words "removed ngram model package"). No replacement for this functionality has been provided.

The package `nltk.model` is still [present](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.model.html) in the NLTK 3.0 source tree, but it is not part of the distribution. So in principle you could download the source and get it to work, but given the bugs that led to its removal, it's probably a better idea to do without it, or to roll your own. Random text generation is not very interesting unless you control the generation algorithm, anyway.